# Keyboard overrides the button at bottom of screen in iOS simulator only

Tags: ios, react-native, tpkeyboardavoiding

I have been trying to scroll my button above the keyboard when keyboard opens, I am using "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view", it becomes handy when I align my button at top just below my text field, but I want my button to be aligned at bottom of screen (flex-end), in this case keyboard covers my button and button doesn't slide up. In Android simulator it is working fine but in iOS it is not. I have tried different things, giving extraScrollHeight also doest work one having one or two text fields and larger screen size. Please suggest something.

[image: Android when keyboard is not opened]
[image: Android when keyboard is opened]

[image: iOS when keyboard is not opened]
[image: iOS when keyboard is opened]

Here is my code.

```
<SafeAreaContainer>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollContainer
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FormikContainer>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
                        onSubmit={values => onSubmitEmail(values)}>
                        {({ values, errors }) => (
                            <FormikInternal>

                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                  
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                />
                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                />
                      
                                <Button bgColor="red">
                                    <Text fontSize={16} color={theme.color.white}>
                                        {LABELS.Continue}
                                    </Text>
                                </Button>
                              
                            </FormikInternal>
                        )
                        }
                    </Formik>
                </FormikContainer>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollContainer>
        </SafeAreaContainer>
```

Styled Components used

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const SafeAreaStyled = styled(SafeAreaView)`
    flex: 1;
    background-color: ${({ backgroundColor, theme }) => backgroundColor || theme.color.white};
    padding-horizontal: ${({ paddingHorizontal }) => `${scale(paddingHorizontal)}px`};
    padding-vertical: ${({ paddingVertical }) => `${scale(paddingVertical)}px`};
`;

export const KeyboardAwareScrollContainer = styled(KeyboardAwareScrollView)`
    background-color: ${({ backgroundColor, theme }) => backgroundColor || theme.color.white};
`;
export const FormikContainer = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: ${scale(32)}px;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.white};
`;
export const FormikContainer = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: ${scale(32)}px;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.white};
`;
```

I am thinking of making keyboard opening listeners and giving button margin of keyboard height when keyboard is open but that's last solution, if any thing else, please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can made it working on iOS using keyboard height. You can make a custom hook for getting keyboard height and give button margin from bottom according to keyboard height. It will work for iOS and for android above code works fine.

UseKeyboardHook

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

export const useKeyboard = () => {
    const [keyboardHeight, setKeyboardHeight] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', e => {
            setKeyboardHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
        });
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
            setKeyboardHeight(0);
        });
        return () => {
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);
    return keyboardHeight;
};
```

Component having keyboard aware scroll view

```
export const YourComponent = () => {
    
    const keyboardHeight = useKeyboard();
    return(
           <SafeAreaContainer>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollContainer
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FormikContainer>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
                        onSubmit={values => onSubmitEmail(values)}>
                        {({ values, errors }) => (
                            <FormikInternal>

                                <TextInput
                                    style={styles.input}
                                    onChangeText={ (val) => {console.log(val);}}
                                    value={values.email}
                                  
                                />
                                <Button bgColor="red" marginBottom={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? keyboardHeight: 0}>
                                    <Text fontSize={16} color={theme.color.white}>
                                        {LABELS.Continue}
                                    </Text>
                                </Button>
                              
                            </FormikInternal>
                        )
                        }
                    </Formik>
                </FormikContainer>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollContainer>
        </SafeAreaContainer>)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this alternatively https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: That doesn't even scroll text fields in my case.